# Does synchronized if apply to whole block

Tags: java, synchronization

This is not a question about method synchronisation, only to statement synchronisation. Please do not incorrectly mark as duplicate.

Is this code:

```
synchronized (this) if (something)
{
    somecode();
    somemorecode();
}
```

equivalent to this code:

```
if (something)
{
    synchronized (this)
    {
        somecode();
        somemorecode();
    }
}
```

Comment: My IDE tells me that your first form (once typos corrected) is not valid syntax - `synchronized` requires a block I think: a single statement is not allowed.  `synchronized (this) { if (something) { ... } }` is valid (braces added) and it is now clear that the `if` is in the sync block, rather than attaching a condition to it - i.e. Java is not Ruby!

Comment: Even if it's valid, don't ever do it. Just don't. Please.

Comment: So does mine, I had not noticed the tiny red squiggle. And yes, I was bringing the question with me from another languqage.

Comment: @Paul: Not just your IDE, the JLS requires it. Nice catch! I've updated my answer to say that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this code...equivalent to this code

No, it isn't. In your first example, the `if` test <s>is</s> might be *inside* the synchronized section. In your second example, the `if` is **outside** the synchronized section.

This is a syntax error:

```
synchronized (this) if (something)
{
    somecode();
    somemorecode();
}
```

`synchronized` **requires** a block, per [JLS§14.19](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.19):

> *SynchronizedStatement*:
>   
>  `synchronized` ( [*Expression*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-Expression) ) [*Block*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-Block)

**If** it were valid, it would probably be equivalent to:

```
synchronized (this)
{
    if (something)
    {
        somecode();
        somemorecode();
    }
}
```

...but that's pure speculation; if it's not defined by the JLS, who knows what it would be. :-)

---

Side note: It's `synchronized`, not `syncronized` or `syncronised`.

Comment: Ooops I typed in the question wrong. I was trying to ask if it was the same as your answer, or somehow the syncronization only applied to the code within the if clause.

Comment: @SteveWaring: Ah! :-)

Comment: The problem of being a UK English user, Every now and then you type in a word like colour or syncrinised. The IDE picks them up.

Comment: If it would have been valid, I would probably read it the other way around. I.e synchronize on this if it's valid:  `if(something) { synchronized(this) { ... } }`

Comment: @AlexisC.: That would be unlike all other uses of single statements vs. blocks (`if`, `while`, ...)

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I'm following you on this :-)

Comment: `while (condition) if (otherCondition) { doSomething(); }` puts the `if` **inside** the `while`, not outside it.

Comment: Ah yes of course. But the first OP's example is really counter-intuitive if you don't know the rules (maybe that's why it's not allowed)..

Comment: @AlexisC.: Yeah, that's entirely possible. :-)